# ionic v3 with socket.io gives unsupported protocol version

Tags: node.js, sockets, ionic-framework, socket.io

I want to use socket.io client in ionic v3, The server is successfully working here. http://165.*******:4000/ but using it in ionic with     `"ng-socket-io": "^0.2.4"` package it throws `Unsupported protocol version`

Can anyone have solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the `socket.io-client` protocol version (EIO) from `ng-socket-io` package is outdated in relation to `socket.io` protocol version in your server.

Comment: Exactly the server and client version was mismatched. Thanks @Diego